# How can I simply test the XPCOM component in the latest firefox?

Tags: c++, firefox, testing, xpcom

In the latest firefox, I found that, when you try to use the following code in web console:

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");

[10:33:00.787] Use of enablePrivilege is deprecated.  
Please use code that runs with the system principal (e.g. an extension) instead.
```

For the firefox 3.6, I always use this way to simply test some of my XPCOM components, it's very convenient. But in the latest firefox, I found that i cannot be used anymore.

So If currently I have written a C++ XPCOM component, is there a simple way that I can try to test it besides having to write and register another `test component`?

Of course, any suggestion is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Binary (C++) XPCOM usage is *very* heavily discouraged (or to put it more firmly, **DEAD DEAD DEAD**) in recent Firefox builds:

- http://adblockplus.org/blog/binary-xpcom-components-are-dead-js-ctypes-is-the-way-to-go
- http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2011/07/add-ons-binary-components-and-js-ctypes/
- http://hackademix.net/2011/07/14/killing-binary-xpcom-in-add-ons-is-javascript-fit/

MDN specifies alternatives for getting binary XPCOM components, although I don't know if any are an improvement for your scenario:

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Firefox_addons_developer_guide/Using_XPCOM—Implementing_advanced_processes

Formerly binary components *should* now use js-ctypes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes

Comment: Thanks for the detail suggestion. Actually, I want to use the log4cplus into my self components, because it is a c++ library, so it is not very easy to use with the js-ctypes, cause the exported symbol table is "Name mangling" by the compiler.